# X3 parse rule doesn't compile

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I'm learning Boost Spirit by writing a parser that parses two variants of hex number used by NAMS:

1. Hex number with either suffix of `0x`/`0h` or prefix of `h`/`x`.
2. Hex number with prefix of `$` and must be followed by a *decimal* digit.

Here is what I have come up so far and with [Coliru Session](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4912102900ddfa60):

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_extended_variant.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace ast {
    struct hex_data : std::string {};
    struct pascal_hex_data : std::string {};

    struct declared_data : boost::spirit::extended_variant<hex_data, pascal_hex_data>
    {
        declared_data () : base_type ()                              { std::cout << "ctor default\n";               } 
        declared_data (hex_data const& rhs) : base_type (rhs)        { std::cout << "ctor hex: " << rhs << "\n";    } 
        declared_data (pascal_hex_data const& rhs) : base_type (rhs) { std::cout << "ctor pascal: " << rhs << "\n"; } 
    };

} // namespace ast

typedef x3::rule<struct hex_digits_class,     std::string>          hex_digit_type;
typedef x3::rule<struct hex_data_class,       ast::hex_data>        hex_data_type;
typedef x3::rule<struct pascalhex_data_class, ast::pascal_hex_data> pascalhex_data_type;
typedef x3::rule<struct declared_data_class,  ast::declared_data>   declared_data_type;

const hex_data_type       hex_data       = "hex_data";
const hex_digit_type      hex_digit      = "hex_digit";
const pascalhex_data_type pascalhex_data = "pascal_hex_data";
const declared_data_type  declared_data  = "declared_data";

auto const hex_digit_def =
  = x3::skip(x3::char_('_'))
      [
        x3::no_case
        [
          x3::char_ ('0', '9') | x3::char_ ("a", "f")
        ]
      ]
  ;

auto const hex_data_def 
  = x3::no_case[x3::lit ("0h") | "0x"] >> +hex_digit_def
  | +hex_digit_def >> x3::no_case[x3::lit ("h") | "x"]
  ;

auto const pascalhex_data_def 
  = x3::lit ("$") >> x3::char_ ('0', '9') >> +hex_digit_def;

auto const declared_data_def 
  = hex_data_def
  | pascalhex_data_def
  ;

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE (hex_digit, hex_data, pascalhex_data, declared_data)

struct Visitor
{
    using result_type = std::string;
    std::string operator()(ast::hex_data const & v) const        { return "hex_data";        } 
    std::string operator()(ast::pascal_hex_data const & v) const { return "pascal_hex_data"; } 
};

int main()
{
  std::string input = "$9";
  ast::declared_data parsed;

  bool r =
    x3::parse (input.begin (), input.end (),
               declared_data_def,
               parsed);

  std::cout << "r = " << r << "\n";
  Visitor v;
  std::cout << "result = " << boost::apply_visitor(v, parsed) << "\n";
}
```

However, the rule `pascalhex_data_def` fails to compile with error message that looks like spirit is deducing the attribute of the rule to be a fusion tuple of `char` and `vector` of `variant` even though the rule is specified to have attribute of an ast derived from `string`:

```
typedef x3::rule<struct pascalhex_data_class, ast::pascal_hex_data> pascalhex_data_type;
```

Can anyone point out why the attribute deduced by boost is not what's specified? Anyway to force the rule to generate string rather than the `tuple` boost is trying to return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code seems extremely complicated for what it achieves. However, after looking at it for considerable time, I noticed you are declaring rules (which coerce their attribute types), but not using them at the crucial time:

```
auto const declared_data_def = hex_data_def | pascalhex_data_def;
```

This means you directly build an expression tree from the expression template (`_def`) initializers, instead of the rules:

```
auto const declared_data_def = hex_data | pascalhex_data;
```

That compiles. It still leaves quite some issues:

- you can/should do without the variant constructors:

  ```
  struct declared_data : boost::spirit::extended_variant<hex_data, pascal_hex_data> {
      using extended_variant::extended_variant;
  };
  ```
- You can write `x3::char_ ('0', '9')` as `x3::char_("0-9")`, so you can write

  ```
  x3::no_case
  [
      x3::char_ ('0', '9') | x3::char_ ("a", "f")
  ]
  ```

  instead as

  ```
  x3::no_case [ x3::char_ ("0-9a-f") ]
  ```

  or even

  ```
  x3::char_ ("0-9a-fA-F")
  ```

  or, maybe just:

  ```
  x3::xdigit
  ```
- `hex_digits_type` declares a `std::string` attribute, but parses only a a single character. Instead of using `+hex_digits_def`, just use `hex_digits` and write:

  ```
  auto const hex_digits_def = x3::skip(x3::char_('_')) [ +x3::xdigit ];
  ```
- your definition

  ```
  "$" >> x3::char_("0-9") >> hex_digits
  ```

  consumes the first digit of the hex number. That's leading to error (parsing the empty string for e.g. `$9`). Instead you probably want to check with `operator&`:

  ```
  '$' >> &x3::char_("0-9") >> hex_digits
  ```

  or, indeed:

  ```
  '$' >> &x3::digit >> hex_digits
  ```
- none of the rules are actually recursive, so none of them require any separation of declaration and definition. This reduces the code by a huge margin

### Simplify, step 1

I suspect you want to *interpret* the hex data as numbers, not string. You could/should probably simplify the AST accordingly. Step 1: drop the distinction between things parsed from 1 or the other format:

```
namespace ast {
    using hex_literal = std::string;
}
```

Now the whole program simplifies to **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/036801f71ef79547)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace ast {
    using hex_literal = std::string;
}

namespace parser {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    auto const hex_digits = x3::rule<struct hex_digits_class, ast::hex_literal> {"hex_digits"} 
                          = x3::skip(x3::char_('_')) [ +x3::xdigit ];

    auto const hex_qualifier = x3::omit [ x3::char_("hxHX") ];

    auto const hex_literal = 
        ('$' >> &x3::xdigit | '0' >> hex_qualifier) >> hex_digits
        | hex_digits >> hex_qualifier;
}

int main()
{
    for (std::string const input : { 
            "$9",   "0x1b",   "0h1c",   "1dh",   "1ex",
            "$9_f", "0x1_fb", "0h1_fc", "1_fdh", "1_fex"
    }) {
        ast::hex_literal parsed;

        bool r = parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser::hex_literal, parsed);
        std::cout << "r = " << std::boolalpha << r << ", result = " << parsed << "\n";
    }
}
```

Printing:

```
r = true, result = 9
r = true, result = 1b
r = true, result = 1c
r = true, result = 1d
r = true, result = 1e
r = true, result = 9f
r = true, result = 1fb
r = true, result = 1fc
r = true, result = 1fd
r = true, result = 1fe
```

## Step 2 (breaking the underscore parsing)

Now, it seems obvious that really, you want to know the numeric value:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f780071e3fd438b)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace ast {
    using hex_literal = uintmax_t;
}

namespace parser {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    auto const hex_qualifier = x3::omit [ x3::char_("hxHX") ];

    auto const hex_literal 
        = ('$' >> &x3::xdigit | '0' >> hex_qualifier) >> x3::hex
        | x3::hex >> hex_qualifier
        ;
}

int main()
{
    for (std::string const input : { 
            "$9",   "0x1b",   "0h1c",   "1dh",   "1ex",
            "$9_f", "0x1_fb", "0h1_fc", "1_fdh", "1_fex"
    }) {
        ast::hex_literal parsed;

        auto f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
        bool r = parse(f, l, parser::hex_literal, parsed) && f==l;

        std::cout << std::boolalpha
             << "r = "            << r
             << ",\tresult = "    << parsed
             << ",\tremaining: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Printing

```
r = true,   result = 9, remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 27,    remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 28,    remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 29,    remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 30,    remaining: ''
r = false,  result = 9, remaining: '_f'
r = false,  result = 1, remaining: '_fb'
r = false,  result = 1, remaining: '_fc'
r = false,  result = 1, remaining: '1_fdh'
r = false,  result = 1, remaining: '1_fex'
```

### Step 3: Make it work with underscores again

This is where I'd start considering a custom parser. This is because it will start involving a semantic action¹ as well as multiple attribute coercions, and frankly it's most convenient to package them up so you can just write imperative C++14 like anyone else:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db6c4306546c53fa)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace ast {
    using hex_literal = uintmax_t;
}

namespace parser {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    struct hex_literal_type : x3::parser_base {
        using attribute_type = ast::hex_literal;

        template <typename It, typename Ctx, typename RCtx>
        static bool parse(It& f, It l, Ctx& ctx, RCtx&, attribute_type& attr) {
            std::string digits;

            skip_over(f, l, ctx); // pre-skip using surrounding skipper

            auto constexpr max_digits = std::numeric_limits<attribute_type>::digits / 8;
            auto digits_ = x3::skip(x3::as_parser('_')) [x3::repeat(1, max_digits) [ x3::xdigit ] ];

            auto qualifier = x3::omit [ x3::char_("hxHX") ];
            auto forms
                = ('$' >> &x3::digit | '0' >> qualifier) >> digits_
                | digits_ >> qualifier
                ;

            if (x3::parse(f, l, forms, digits)) {
                attr = std::stoull(digits, nullptr, 16);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    hex_literal_type static const hex_literal;
}

int main() {
    for (std::string const input : { 
            "$9",   "0x1b",   "0h1c",   "1dh",   "1ex",
            "$9_f", "0x1_fb", "0h1_fc", "1_fdh", "1_fex",
            // edge cases
            "ffffffffH", // fits
            "1ffffffffH", // too big
            "$00_00___01___________0__________0", // fine
            "0x", // fine, same as "0h"
            "$",
            // upper case
            "$9",   "0X1B",   "0H1C",   "1DH",   "1EX",
            "$9_F", "0X1_FB", "0H1_FC", "1_FDH", "1_FEX",
    }) {
        ast::hex_literal parsed = 0;

        auto f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
        bool r = parse(f, l, parser::hex_literal, parsed) && f==l;

        std::cout << std::boolalpha
             << "r = "            << r
             << ",\tresult = "    << parsed
             << ",\tremaining: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

> **Note** how I included `max_digits` to avoid runaway parsing (say when the input has 10 gigabyte of hex digits). You might want improve this by preskipping insignificant `0` digits.

The output is now:

```
r = true,   result = 9, remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 27,    remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 28,    remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 29,    remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 30,    remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 159,   remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 507,   remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 508,   remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 509,   remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 510,   remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 4294967295,    remaining: ''
r = false,  result = 0, remaining: '1ffffffffH'
r = true,   result = 256,   remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 0, remaining: ''
r = false,  result = 0, remaining: '$'
r = true,   result = 9, remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 27,    remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 28,    remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 29,    remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 30,    remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 159,   remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 507,   remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 508,   remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 509,   remaining: ''
r = true,   result = 510,   remaining: ''
```

### Step 4: Icing on the cake

In case you wanted to retain the input format for roundtripping you could trivially add that to the AST now:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdb07940b29a0317)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace ast {
    struct hex_literal {
        uintmax_t value;
        std::string source;
    };
}

namespace parser {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    struct hex_literal_type : x3::parser_base {
        using attribute_type = ast::hex_literal;

        template <typename It, typename Ctx, typename RCtx>
        static bool parse(It& f, It l, Ctx& ctx, RCtx&, attribute_type& attr) {
            std::string digits;

            skip_over(f, l, ctx); // pre-skip using surrounding skipper
            It b = f; // save start

            auto constexpr max_digits = std::numeric_limits<decltype(attr.value)>::digits / 8;
            auto digits_ = x3::skip(x3::as_parser('_')) [x3::repeat(1, max_digits) [ x3::xdigit ] ];

            auto qualifier = x3::omit [ x3::char_("hxHX") ];
            auto forms
                = ('$' >> &x3::digit | '0' >> qualifier) >> digits_
                | digits_ >> qualifier
                ;

            if (x3::parse(f, l, forms, digits)) {
                attr.value = std::stoull(digits, nullptr, 16);
                attr.source.assign(b,l);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    hex_literal_type static const hex_literal;
}

int main()
{
    for (std::string const input : { 
            "$9",   "0x1b",   "0h1c",   "1dh",   "1ex",
            "$9_f", "0x1_fb", "0h1_fc", "1_fdh", "1_fex",
            // edge cases
            "ffffffffH", // fits
            "1ffffffffH", // too big
            "$00_00___01___________0__________0", // fine
            "0x", // fine, same as "0h"
            "$",
            // upper case
            "$9",   "0X1B",   "0H1C",   "1DH",   "1EX",
            "$9_F", "0X1_FB", "0H1_FC", "1_FDH", "1_FEX",
    }) {
        ast::hex_literal parsed = {};

        auto f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
        bool r = parse(f, l, parser::hex_literal, parsed) && f==l;

        if (r) {
            std::cout << "result = " << parsed.value
                      << ",\tsource = '" << parsed.source << "'\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "FAILED"
                      << ",\tremaining: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
result = 9, source = '$9'
result = 27,    source = '0x1b'
result = 28,    source = '0h1c'
result = 29,    source = '1dh'
result = 30,    source = '1ex'
result = 159,   source = '$9_f'
result = 507,   source = '0x1_fb'
result = 508,   source = '0h1_fc'
result = 509,   source = '1_fdh'
result = 510,   source = '1_fex'
result = 4294967295,    source = 'ffffffffH'
FAILED, remaining: '1ffffffffH'
result = 256,   source = '$00_00___01___________0__________0'
result = 0, source = '0x'
FAILED, remaining: '$'
result = 9, source = '$9'
result = 27,    source = '0X1B'
result = 28,    source = '0H1C'
result = 29,    source = '1DH'
result = 30,    source = '1EX'
result = 159,   source = '$9_F'
result = 507,   source = '0X1_FB'
result = 508,   source = '0H1_FC'
result = 509,   source = '1_FDH'
result = 510,   source = '1_FEX'
```

---

¹ [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

Comment: Added 2 more takes that address all the remaining issues.

Comment: For comparison, look at this similar task in Spirit Qi https://stackoverflow.com/a/29195187/85371 a few years back

Comment: Thanks so much. I think my biggest issue was the confusion between the typedef of the rules and declaration of rule, and when to use which.

Comment: Rule of thumb: The rule does (a) compilation firewalling (b) attribute coercion. If you need either, use the rule.